# Time taken to sort numbers in Linked List

Tags: sorting, data-structures, linked-list

Does Sorting take the same time if we use the Singly Linked List or Doubly Linked List?

I want to sort random numbers.

(I know it differs greatly in terms of insertion/removal of elements in  Singly/Doubly Linked List)

But Does it take almost same time regardless of which data structure (Singly / Doubly LinkedList) we use or which sorting technique we implement to sort the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest sort methods used for linked lists only needs to use the next pointer of a linked list to do a variation of bottom up merge sort, using an array of pointers (typically 26 to 32 pointers) to nodes, where array[i] is NULL or a pointer to a list with 2 to the power i nodes. Example code below.

Sorting a double linked list is going to be slower than sorting a single linked list if time is spent maintaining previous pointers during the sort. If only using next pointers during the sort, the time is about the same, other than larger nodes (since they have previous pointers) consume more cache space.  Doing a single pass to set the previous pointers after the sort should be faster than maintaining previous pointers during the sort.

```
NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst = NULL;                      /* destination head ptr */
NODE **ppDst = &pDst;                   /* ptr to head or prev->next */
    if(pSrc1 == NULL)
        return pSrc2;
    if(pSrc2 == NULL)
        return pSrc1;
    while(1){
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            pSrc2 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc2->next));
            if(pSrc2 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc1;
                break;
            }
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            if(pSrc1 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pDst;
}

#define NUMLISTS 32                     /* size of aList[] */
NODE * SortList(NODE *pList)
{
NODE * aList[NUMLISTS];                 /* array of lists */
NODE * pNode;
NODE * pNext;
int i;
    if(pList == NULL)                   /* check for empty list */
        return NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)       /* zero array */
        aList[i] = NULL;
    pNode = pList;                      /* merge nodes into array */
    while(pNode != NULL){
        pNext = pNode->next;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i] != NULL); i++){
            pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
            aList[i] = NULL;
        }
        if(i == NUMLISTS)
            i--;
        aList[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;
    }
    pNode = NULL;                       /* merge array into one list */
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)
        pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}
```

Comment: rcgldr, Thanks for sharing this...Would you please share any link for this algorithm?
and one que: 
**although the sort itself takes the same time, an additional pass is needed to fix up the previous pointers, so it takes a bit longer**

Is this true for all sorting technieque like mergeSort or bubbleSort or any other?

Comment: @inityk -  This algorithm is used in std::list::sort() in HP / Microsoft, look at < list >, which is a template source file . It's the fastest way to sort a linked list. For < list > sort, splice and merge are used to move / merge nodes, and they update previous pointers during the process. My example only uses next pointers so it can be used for single or double linked lists, so the previous pointers are fixed post-sort. There may be a slight performance advantage to doing a post-sort fix of previous pointers.

Comment: @inityk - In my answer, I updated the paragraphs to better answer you question. Continuing with my comment, looking at the bottom of all the HP / Microsoft template files, there's a 1994 date on most of them, so these algorithms have been around a long time. The linked list sort using array isn't as well known as the common sorts used for arrays or vectors (mergesort, quicksort, heapsort, ...).