# Time complexity of divide step in merge sort applied to linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, mergesort

I have been looking at the application of merge sort to linked lists. Some of the articles I have looked at tout that merge sort is the best algorithm for sorting a linked list. It makes sense for the conquer part in the divide and conquer strategy where you merge the two sorted linked lists as you end up saving on required memory (compared to an array). But, what I don't understand is the time complexity of the divide step in the algorithm.

For an array, this step is constant time by leveraging random access and splitting the array into smaller chunks. But, for a linked list isn't this going to take an additional O(n)? I have seen Floyd's algorithm (tortoise-hare) used to find the mid-point of a linked list and divide the problem into smaller chunks. I did some analysis on the divide step. Suppose the linked list is of size n, then the # of operations involved in just dividing the problem is as follows,

`n/2 + n/4 * 2 + n/8 * 4 + ... = n/2 * log(n)`

From the above, it looks like compared to the array case, an additional factor of "n" appears from Floyd's algorithm. So, the final time complexity would be O(n^2 * log(n)). Can someone please explain the discrepancy?

Edit: based on @Yves comment, I identified the mistake,

I multiplied the work while merging back the sorted blocks from bottom to top when it should be added. So, the net time would be: nlogn/2 + nlogn = O(nlogn),

This is probably is most valid answer to the above question; other answers are a bit indirect/ provide no explanation

Comment: How does your n log(n)/2 becomes an O(n² log(n)) ?

Comment: @Yves Thank you! I made a mistake in the analysis, will correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your question is that the additional O(n/2) time complexity for the scanning of half a sub-list for each level of recursion translates into an overall time complexity of O((0.5 n log(n) + 1.0 (n log(n)) = O(1.5 n log(n)), not O(n^2 (log(n))), and O(1.5 (n log(n))) translates into O(n log(n)), since time complexity ignores lower order terms or constants. However in my actual testing for a large list with scattered nodes, where most node accesses result in a cache miss, my benchmarks show an relative time complexity of recursive versus iterative to be O(1.4 n log(n)), using a count based scan to split lists, rather than tortoise-hare approach.

For recursive version, using tortoise-hare approach is relatively slow and can be improved by using a count of nodes, which may require a one time scan of n node if the linked list container doesn't maintain a count of nodes (for example C++ std::list::size()). The reduces the overhead to advancing a single pointer halfway (sub-count / 2) through a linked list run.

Example C / C++ code:

[Time taken to sort numbers in Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826237/33827270#33827270)

However, in such a case (large list, scattered nodes), it is faster to copy the data from the list into an array, sort the array, then create a new sorted list from the sorted array. This is because elements in an array are merged sequentially (not via random linked list next pointers), which is cache friendly.

Comment: can you please elaborate, not sure I understand "The time complexity is the same, but that is ignoring constant factors", same as what?

Comment: @SahilGupta - I updated my answer, time complexity for both is O(n log(n)), but top down is slower than bottom up by a linear factor O(n). The number of level of recursions for top down is about the same as the number of array entries used for bottom up, but there's no scanning to mid-point for bottom up, so it's faster by a linear factor O(n) or ~O(n/2) if including constants.

Comment: you answer/comment was insightful in understanding the application of merge sort to linked lists, but didn’t answer my original question/ I misinterpreted

Comment: @SahilGupta - I updated my answer. I hope it answers your question now.

Answer (score 0):

In top-down merge sort, finding the place where to split the list takes time proportional to the length of the list to split. At each recursion level, the total time for these is proportional to the lengths of all sublists, ie: to the length of the original list. The number of recursion levels is **log2(length(L))** so the overall time complexity involved in splitting the lists is **O(length(L) * log2(length(L)))** the same complexity as the merge phases.

In bottom-up merge sort, the list is split one element at a time and this singleton is either stored into the first element of the sublist array or merged with it to store into the second element etc. Hence splitting the list only adds linear time, which explains why bottom-up merging is usually faster than top-down. Other factors contributing to the implementation efficiency are cache-friendliness, which is usually better in bottom-up and balancing lengths, which is more difficult to achieve in bottom-up merge sort.

Here is a simple example of bottom-up merge sort for lists:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
    struct list *next;
    int value;
} list;

list *list_merge(list *a, list *b) {
    list *head, **tailp = &head;
    while (a && b) {
        if (a->value <= b->value) {
            *tailp = a;
            a = a->next;
        } else {
            *tailp = b;
            b = b->next;
        }
        tailp = &(*tailp)->next;
    }
    *tailp = a ? a : b;
    return head;
}

list *list_mergesort(list *p) {
    list *a[sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT];
    list *e;
    size_t i, top = 0;

    while (p) {
        e = p;
        p = p->next;
        e->next = NULL;
        for (i = 0;; i++) {
            if (i == top) {
                a[top++] = e;
                break;
            }
            if (a[i] == NULL) {
                a[i] = e;
                break;
            }
            e = list_merge(a[i], e);
            a[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    e = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < top; i++) {
        e = list_merge(a[i], e);
    }
    return e;
}

list *list_append(list **headp, int value) {
    list *e = malloc(sizeof *e);
    if (e) {
        e->next = NULL;
        e->value = value;
        while (*headp)
            headp = &(*headp)->next;
        *headp = e;
    }
    return e;
}

void list_print(list *e) {
    while (e) {
        printf("%d%c", e->value, " \n"[!e->next]);
        e = e->next;
    }
}

void list_free(list *head) {
    while (head) {
        list *e = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(e);
    }
}

int main() {
    list *head = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        list_append(&head, rand());
    head = list_mergesort(head);
    list_print(head);
    list_free(head);
    return 0;
}
```